# If the commuter gets home by 5:30 pm, what is the probability that he used the compact car?

Tags: probability

> A Commuter owns **2 cars**, **1  compact** and **1  standard model (a larger one)**.   About **75%** of the time he uses the **compact** to travel to work, and about **25%** of the time the **larger car** is used.  When he uses the **compact car**, he usually gets home by **5:30 P.M.** about **75%** of the time; if he uses the **standard-size car**, he gets home by **5:30 P.M.** about **60%** of the time.

If he gets home at **5:30 P.M.**, what is the probability that he used the compact car?

My answer was: $$\frac{75}{135}\cdot \frac{75}{100}= \frac{5}{12}$$ But I think I have not got that right.

Please explain to me how to arrive at the right answer.

Comment: This is a conditional probability question.  You have to divide the probability that the commuter gets home by 5:30 pm if he uses the compact car by the total probability that he gets home by 5:30 pm.

Comment: and how to get the total probablity if he gets home by 5:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be the event that the commuter used the compact car; let $S$ be the event that the commuter used the standard model; let $H$ be the event that the commuter makes it home by 5:30 pm.  We are given 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(C) & = 0.75\\
\Pr(S) & = 0.25\\
\Pr(H \mid C) & = 0.75\\
\Pr(H \mid S) & = 0.60
\end{align*}
We wish to compute the conditional probability that the commuter used the compact car given that he gets home by 5:30 pm.
$$\Pr(C \mid H) = \frac{\Pr(C \cap H)}{\Pr(H)} = \frac{\Pr(C)\Pr(H \mid C)}{\Pr(C)\Pr(H \mid C) + \Pr(S)\Pr(H \mid S)}$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: using the rule you gave I got the answer being 15\19

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Blast! I reversed the numbers! (Thanks, N.F. Taussig).  The person used the compact car 75% of the time so 1500 of the 2000 times.  He arrived home before 5:30 75% of those times or 1125 times.  25% of the time, 500 times, he uses the standard car.  He arrives home before 5:30 60% or those times or 300 times.

He arrives home before 5:30 a total of 1125+ 300= 1425 times.  Of those 1425 times he was driving the compact car 1125 times.  The probability he was driving the compact car, given that he arrived home by 5:30, was 1125/1425= 225/285= 45/57.

Comment: Good.  Please delete your other answer.